# C# winforms - Can't find the text file created at Application.ExecutablePath location

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a text file at executablePath location.

```
 Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Paths.txt";
```

The application works perfectly fine, but for some weird reason when I check the executable directory, the text file is not there.

I have a feeling that it creates the file at some other location, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm creating the file like this;

```
string PathsDirectory =Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+"\\Paths.txt";
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(PathsDirectory);
tw.WriteLine(Data);
tw.Close();
```

And reading it like this;

```
string PathsDirectory =Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+"\\Paths.txt";
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(PathsDirectory);
string line;
while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

I checked the path after concat and everything looks fine except I can't see the file there.

Ok finally I found the file it's inside;

C:\Users\Alican\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\MyMovies\MyMovies

insted of

C:\Program Files (x86)\MyMovies\MyMovies

Comment: You should show the code that creates the file and the code that checks its existance

Comment: Have you verified with the debugger what the path is after your string concatination?

Comment: Are you wrapping that code in a `Try...Catch` block? If so, you might be catching an exception which is causing the file to not be created but your program to continue running. Alternatively, you could try using [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "Paths.txt");`

Comment: Tried every possible way and still can't see the file. I also put a message box showing me the path just before the file is created and it's perfectly fine.

Comment: does the account running the program have access to write to that directory? Also, as @keyboardP suggests, are you catching and not handling exceptions?

Comment: wow it creates the file at this location; C:\Users\Alican\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\MyMovies\MyMovies  What is virtualstore and why is it putting it there?

Comment: Is your application a virtual app? like AppV, Cameyo, or ThinApp? If so, that is why - all file IO is redirected to the "virtual" locations.

Comment: Yes you're right my application is Appv. Thanks for the info I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider your level of rights when the application is running.

The fact that it's going into the `VirtualStore` folder tells me that you don't have sufficient rights to write into the ProgramFiles directory as you would like.

Try running as Admin.  Generally, writing into the `ProgramFiles` directory is a bad idea.  I would recommend writing to the user space with something like this:

```
String PathsDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Paths.txt");
```

That `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum provides all of the standard user-accessible locations, also things like `Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it worked in my computer:

```
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\path.txt";
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
tw.WriteLine("How are you?");
tw.Close();
Console.WriteLine(filePath);
```

I've looked inside the directory and the file is right there, and contains the phrase I wrote:

```
c:\CDash\tests\path\path\bin\Debug\path.txt
```